# Handling JSF page getting blank after Session has expired

Tags: jsf

I have JSF pages which have links to other JSF pages .  When I click on the link and if the session has already expired , control goes to login page. And I will login with username password and again come to same page where I have clicked on link.  Now I will click on the link, a blank page is getting displayed, and if i do page refresh by F5, the expected page loads.

And also I have checked the console on my Jboss server, the View Expired exception is not appearing.

SO I am bit confused which way I handle this to avoid blank page getting displayed.

Please help.

Comment: can you update with relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if you're performing link navigation by ajax and the page returned after login was been served from the browser cache (and thus contains a form with an outdated view state identifier). You need to tell the browser to not cache restricted pages. You can achieve this with the following filter:

```
@WebFilter(servletNames={"Faces Servlet"})
public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        if (!req.getRequestURI().startsWith(req.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { // Skip JSF resources (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
            res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
            res.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
            res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note that this problem thus also suggests that you're using (ajax) command links for page-to-page navigation. This is a bad practice. Those links are not SEO friendly nor bookmarkable. Command links should be used for form submits only. Use normal links for page-to-page navigation. See also [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)

Comment: @BalusC, but when I use command link with Post Redirect Get pattern, is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

@BaluSC : Thanks for the reply.

Used h:outputLink wherever possible.
And also I have handled the ViewExpiredException through the  tag in web.xml.

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/ErrorHandler</location>
  </error-page>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.common.beans.ErrorHandler</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ErrorHandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ErrorHandler</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Used a servlet which  handles this exception and redirects to the same page and loads the page properly.
And the doGet method of Servlet checks for ViewExpiredException.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
 {

      if (request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception") != null
         && request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.exception")
            .toString().contains("ViewExpiredException"))
      {

            String[] attributes =
               request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri")
                  .toString().split("/");
            StringBuilder redirectViewId = new StringBuilder("");
            for (int i = 2; i < attributes.length; i++)
            {
               redirectViewId.append("/").append(attributes[i]);
            }
            response.sendRedirect(FacesUtils.getFullRequestUrl(request)
               + redirectViewId);
         }
}
```